# B. W. Kernighan and M. E. Lesk, LEARN - Computer-Aided Instruction on UNIX

Tags: command-line, application

B. W. Kernighan and M. E. Lesk, LEARN - Computer-Aided Instruction on UNIX

Is this program somewhere available?

In an old book on Unix, I read about a command line program called `learn`, which could be used as a tutorial to Unix.

You can find further information but unfortunately no source on it on https://itservices.usc.edu/unix/commands/learn/.

There is also information about it on https://www.unix.com/man-page/bsd/1/LEARN/.

My question therefore is, where I could find the source (in case it is open sourced) or even better a package of it for current *Linux* distributions.

There is a repository on GitHub about it https://github.com/chettrick/learn, but if someone knows an additional source, I would be highly interested. The code available there gives me the following error: `Makefile:33: *** missing separator.`

Comment: While an interesting historic curiosity, I can pretty much understand in a world of graphical presentations, web and mobiles, why a "learn" text console command won´t be as valuable as it used to be. But I digress. If you enjoy the idea of `learn` search for `vilearn` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for hint. I certainly agree, but I would say that the best place to learn how to use the Unix command line is the Unix command line itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s also available in [the Unix history repository](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo), *e.g.* in the 4.1c BSD release ([source code](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_1c_2/usr/src/usr.bin/learn), [man page](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_1c_2-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man1/learn.1)), and on [the Unix Tree](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) at TUHS ([source code](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/src/usr.bin/learn), [man page](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/man/man1/learn.1)). The lessons themselves are [available in V7](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/lib/learn), in archives which are extracted by the `Makefile`.

The original V7 version is [available under a BSD license with the advertising clause](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Caldera-license.pdf), so the license isn’t much of an issue.

If someone wanted to package this for a modern distribution, the lessons would really have to be updated...

Comment: Perfect, this was the link I was looking for.